# Did people of prophets time know about organs in human body

Tags: prophet-muhammad

When I read about the incident when jibreal came to prophet muhammed(sw) than took out his heart to wash the heart in zam zam water so I think that people during prophets time knew about the organs like heart otherwise how could Muhammed prophet recognise it as heart.so do people of prophets time have knowledge about organs in human being?